# firebase retrieving data issue after database has updated in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

here my DB is writing correctly and retrieving that data onto web but once there is an update in the DB the updated data are not shown in web..the old data are still shown..but once i refresh the page the updated values are shown any idea to fix this issue?

this is my retrieve data code

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.authListener();
    this.retrieveData();

    console.log("Data loaded");
  }
retrieveData = () => {
    fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        var ref = fire
          .database()
          .ref("data")
          .limitToLast(1);
        //takes the last data in DB

        var userUID = fire.auth().currentUser.uid;
        var query = ref.orderByChild("ID").equalTo(userUID); //retrieves data about only the current logged in user
        console.log(userUID);
        query.once("value", snapshot => {
          let currentState = this.state.people;

          const currentUser = snapshot.val();
          for (let i in currentUser) {
            currentState.push({
              email: currentUser[i].UserEmail,
              UserAnswer: currentUser[i].UserAnswer,
              Questions: currentUser[i].Question,
              id: currentUser[i].ID,
              Score: currentUser[i].Score,
              levelRook: currentUser[i].UserLevel,
              levelStudent: currentUser[i].UserLevelStudent,
              levelIntermediate: currentUser[i].UserLevelIntermediate,
              levelExpert: currentUser[i].UserLevelExpert,
              levelMaster: currentUser[i].UserLevelMaster,
              rank: currentUser[i].RankValue
            });
          }

          // currentState.push(user);
          console.log(currentState);
          this.rankData(); //setting rank value from DB

          this.setState({
            people: currentState,
            dataHasLoaded: true
          });
        });
      } else {
        console.log("no user");
      }
    });
  };
```

the issue is when the DB values are updated the above function is not called again to fetch the latest data ...any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you need to look into Firebase database triggers. If you are asking the view to update when your database is updated outside of you application code.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events

Comment: that is firestore im focusing on firebase